# nvm, node y npm orden no encontrada

Tags: nodejs, npm, nvm

Presento un problema, y es que si accedo desde el sudo en mi Ubuntu, puedo ver y usar node y npm sin problemas, pero si lo hago directamente desde el usuario predeterminado que lo hacia antes, ya no me deja, me dice que npm(comando no reconocido) y tambien node(comando no reconocido), que podria ser esto?
-Nota: Se me ha dañado desde el dia de hoy que me mostro un mensaje para actualizar a la ultima version de Node, y al momento de hacerlo sucedio todo esto.

Imagenes de muestra.

[image: Imagen 1]

[image: Imagen 2]

Añado algunas imagenes mas:
[image: Aqui esta]

La otra imagen:
[image: Aqui esta la otra imagen]

Comment: `iamother` tiene incluido en la variable de entorno `PATH` la ruta a los ejecutables `npm` y `node` al igual que lo tiene `root`?

Comment: Hola Benjamín, Como lo haría? la verdad soy usuario nuevo en Ubuntu.

Comment: Primero hay que ver si eso es el problema. Podrías agregar el output de los siguientes comandos: `echo $PATH` y `which node` para los dos usuarios por favor?

Comment: Listo, he agregado las nuevas imágenes a la publicación original.

Comment: La ruta de la segunda imagen que no se deja ver es esta!
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

Comment: Ya he resuelto el problema, habia instalado nvm y node como root, por ende lo que hice fue desistalarlo de root, e instalarlo desde el usuario principal.